# Temporary rows in static table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, temporary-tables

I'm looking for a way to insert temporary rows in a static table. These rows are temporary because are used only in processing.
The reasons are:

1. I wish not to work in transaction because it's a huge process and i do not need open transactions in every step;
2. I wish not use static rows because I can have multiple executions;
3. I prefer not use temporary table because of keeping execution plans and r/w data in different procedures. Note that:

   - Temporary table are accessed by child procedures but not by parent procedure. If a child procedure must pass data to his parent , you can use exec/insert, but it is limited because you can not nest two exec/insert.
   - Global temp are shared between multiple execution, instead I need that each execution use his data.

I don't like much the current solution, but the state of the art is:

- Every execution generates a GUID=NewID() which is inserted in every row;
- A garbage process deletes old GUIDs.

Thanks

Comment: "*I prefer not use temporary table because of keeping execution plans and r/w data in different procedures*" - Could you please elaborate what you mean by this more?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)